# cv2 and PyQt5 are showing error when used in same environment

Tags: python, pyqt5, ubuntu-20.04, opencv

I am trying to import cv2 first and then QtCore:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import cv2
```

It is showing this error:

```
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /home/pc/anaconda3/envs/MatchNMix_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/../../libopencv_gapi.so.406)
```

Then, tried with import QtCore first and then cv2 :

```
import cv2
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

It is showing this error:

```
ImportError: /home/pc/anaconda3/envs/MatchNMix_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZdaPvm, version Qt_5
```

For,
`opencv==4.6.0 installed using conda`

`pyqt5==5.15.9 installed using pip`

OS: `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`

I am using `libstdc++.so.6.0.29`

I want work with cv2 and pyqt in same virtual environment.

Comment: Each of them work fine when imported individually?

Answer (score 1):

First I cleared the cache from the anaconda using this command:

```
conda clean -all
```

I have installed `opencv=4.6.0` and `pyqt=5.15.7`  using the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv=4.6.0
conda install -c anaconda pyqt=5.15.7
```

Now everything is working.